# Regex - Find everything before and after a dynamic group of characters

Tags: regex

Here's what I'm trying to do. I need to manipulate some Amazon data that's in a spreadsheet. Here's an example of the first cell of text I have in the spreadsheet (the quotes aren't part of the actual spreadsheet cell contents):

"#864 in **Tools & Home Improvement** (Top 100)"

I need to delete everything before and after the category (bold). The category will change - it's not the same in every spreadsheet cell. In the example above "#864 in " would need to be deleted (the number always has a pound sign followed by a number ... 1 through potentially millions, followed by a space, followed by "in", followed by another space).

Also, there will always be " (Top 100)" immediately after the category. I need to find (and ultimately delete) all of that and a bunch of other stuff in the cell (there's a lot of stuff after the " (Top 100) " - I just didn't include it - words, characters, separate lines/paragraphs, etc.).

I only need the category. I'm stuck! Hopefully that makes sense. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you have tried? And which language are you using? Visual Basic or something else?

Comment: You should tag the post with the language you are using.

Comment: I'm not using a specific language. I'm just using Google Spreadsheet's find and replace option with has a regex search option.

Comment: That is important information to include!

Answer (score 0):

In Google Spreadsheets:

Find: `^#\d+ in (.*) \(Top 100\).*`

Replace: `$1`

Comment: I tried that. No luck. Thanks a lot though. I'm using a search and replace in Google Spreadsheets. So I need to find everything before and after the category and then replace everything before and after the category with nothing. That way it will remove everything in the cell besides the category.

Comment: Updated to be specific to Google Spreadsheets. Worked for me with your example string!

Comment: that works perfectly ;-) The only issue I'm having now is that there is a bunch of stuff AFTER the "(Top 100)". Here's a screenshot: https://www.evernote.com/l/ABgP6UxFjI9FHqmTiUyPnqZzGRZCzDpVjks. Each cell has other stuff that needs to be removed also. Any chance you can tweak the regex?

Comment: I'd also be curious if you have a solution for one other regex issue I'm running into. Here's the spreadsheet I'm  currently looking at: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V8IqUD8ezMyvSRNNEcV8PO22OTDRW0bknDYTboWKcRI/edit?usp=sharing. In the last column, each cell ends with a number (it can be any number). I only want to keep the number and delete everything else in the cell. For example, row 2, column I would just be 11,451. Row 3 would be 25, etc. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

**First Requirement:** 
To remove the extra lines after Top 100

Find: `^#[\d,]+ in (.*) \(Top 100\)[\s\S]*`

Replace `$1`

I also noticed another error that if the starting number has commas then the regex wasn't included so I included fix for that too. Now it'll match even '#10,286 in...' etc.

**Second Requirement:** To remove everything in the cell except the last number:

Find: `[\s\S]*?([\d,.]+)$`

Replace `$1`

Replaced 467/468 cells

**Note:** Played around with the data and both regex seem to be working fine. Make sure you select the right column before running the regex replace. Also, keep in mind that the first one won't work for cells that don't have (Top 100) - there were quire a few.

Demo sheet with regex replace performed using above expressions: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15tp7R7_4RR8iZPkxgGUUIsRX1aC_71Q8ULfVYFXVD-s/edit?usp=sharing)

Hope this helps!